# Iterate nested "for" loops only over "specific" indices. C++

Tags: c++, for-loop, iteration, nested-loops

I have 4 nested "for" loops.

```
     for(int i=0; i<len1; i++) {
      for(int j=0; j<len2; j++) {
       for(int k=0; k<len1; k++) {
        for(int l=0; l<len2; l++) {
          //perform some calculations/operations.
        }
       }
      }
     }
```

The thing is, this whole code will run over each and every index of every "for" loop from 0 to len1/len2. I don't want it to do that. Instead, I want these loops to iterate over certain "specific" indices and skip the rest(by skipping I mean TOTAL skipping, it should not iterate over the unwanted indices).

To give a more elaborate explanation, here is how the iterations will happen when the above code snippet is run.

```
i    j    k    l
0    0    0    0
0    0    0    1
0    0    0    2
0    0    0    3
.    .    .    .
.    .    .    .
.    .    .    .
len1 len2 len1 len2
```

But what I want is the following...

```
0    0    0    63
0    0    0    450
0    0    0    569
0    0    3    87
0    0    78   999
.    .    .    .
.    .    .    .
.    .    .    .
29   65   99   357
29   66   21   222
.    .    .    .
```

and so on...
Firstly is it possible with nested "for" loops?

Secondly and most importantly I want to do it only with nested "for" loops. No other method.

Thirdly the iterations over the "specific" indices I want is NOT random.

Comment: `for(int i=0; l<len2; i = GetNextIndex(i))`

Comment: *"the iterations over the "specific" indices I want is NOT random"* Then how is it determined?

Comment: Lets say I have something like {for a specific "i" index with a specific "j" index with a specific "k" index, iterate only over these "l" indices}

Answer (score 1):

If I'm understanding correctly , you want certain indexes (you have a method of determining that ? ) to be iterated.

If you can predetermine the desired indexes then you can use a vector of indices.

Something like :

```
 vector<int> iIdx;
 vector<int> jIdx;
 vector<int> kIdx;
 vector<int> lIdx;

 // your inside algorithm section which determines what indexes are needed for each 
 ...
 lIdx.push_back(63);
 ...

 // the new loop
 for (int i=0;i<iIdx.size();i++)
  for (int j=0;j<jIdx.size();j++)
    for (int k=0;k<kIdx.size();k++)
      for (int l=0;l<lIdx.size();l++)
        {
            ii = iIdx[i];
            jj = jIdx[j]; 
            kk = kIdx[k]; 
            ll = lIdx[l];
            // use ii , jj ,kk and ll as you would use i,j,k,l on your original question
        }
```

This works if you have a way to determine these indexes before the quad loop starts.

Otherwise, you can trim down some loops by this approach at the point where you can generate indexes (for example if you need to know i and j to generate the indexes of k and l, then only kIdx and lIdx will use the above method).

EDIT :

Noted in other comment that you use CUDA.

You can compute the iIdx, jIdx, kIdx and lIdx arrays on the CPU and make the for loops on the GPU.

Comment: I don't think this allows for irregularly shaped areas of the matrix to be covered.

Comment: It doesn't really. But if that's what OP desires, aren't we answering to a X Y problem ?

Answer (score 0):

If you can define the starting point for an inner loop in terms of the outer loops, sure.  Example:

```
for(int i=0; i<len1; i++) {
  for(int j=0; j<len2; j++) {
   for(int k=0; k<len1; k++) {
    int lStart = DetermineBasedOn(i, j, k);
    for(int l=lStart; l<len2; l++) {
      //perform some calculations/operations.
    }
   }
  }
 }
```

Note that

```
DetermineBasedOn(i, j, k);
```

does not have to be an actual method call.  You could set the start index within the body of your loop.

If you need *gaps* in the region that you iterate, do as suggested by @SamIAm in the comments: Provide a function to determine the next index (though possibly based on multiple variables:

```
for(int l=lStart; l<len2; l = GetNextIndex(l, i, j, k)) {
```

You can use the same technique to end an inner loop earlier (setting e.g. `lEnd` and using that in place of `len2`).

> Secondly and most importantly I want to do it only with nested "for" loops. No other method.

`do` and `while` loops are functionally equivalent to `for` loops, and may (or may not) be clearer and easier to read in this case.  I'm not sure why the bias against other loop constructs, but you can certainly accomplish the same result with a `for` as with `do` or `while`.

Comment: I need to use "for" loops so I can make it parallel by using OpenMp or CUDA.

Comment: @MohammadSohaib: CUDA cannot parallelize other loop constructs?  Interesting, but not a problem as they are functionally equivalent to other loop constructs.

Comment: But see "for(int l=lStart; l<len2; l++)" will still run from 'lStart' to 'len2', iterating over every index, no?

Comment: Eric, sorry I am new at parallel programming, maybe it does, but for now I would like to stick to the 'for' loop. I will check into the other loop constructs later. Thanks.

Comment: @MohammadSohaib: I updated my answer to account for "holes" in the area you want to cover.

Comment: I will try this out now.

Answer (score 0):

Put your specific indices into a `std::vector`, and loop over that to get your real indices. With C++ 11, you can use the following syntax to initialize the vector.

```
std::vector myFavoriteIndices = {5,7, 11, 8}

for(int i = 0; i < len1; i++) {
    for(int j = 0; j < len2; j++) {
        for(int k = 0; k < len1; k++) {
            for(int l = 0; l < myFavoriteIndices.size(); l++) {
                int trueIndex = myFavoriteIndices[l];
                // do something with trueIndex
            }
        }
    }
}
```